# Moving back to orginal uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am programming in xcode using xib for design. 
I have uiviewcontroller A.

Now, I present view uiviewcontroller B, which is object of navigation controller.

now, from uiviewcontroller B ,  I push to uiviewcontroller C.

Now, in uiviewcontroller C, there is UIBUTTON. On clicking button , I want to go back to uiviewcontroller A. How should i do that?

Comment: it moves back to uiviewcontroller B because B is root uiviewcontroller of navobject. I want to move back to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Navigation View Controller Vs Modal View Controller

There are two ways you usually show the next view controller.

You either push a view controller onto a navigation stack or you present a view controller modally, which I believe what you're trying to do, since you mention ViewControllerB is a navigation controller.

Modal view controllers aren't pushed onto the navigation stack so you cannot pop it off.

To dismiss a modal view controller that you presented, you need to use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

View Controller B (VCB) in this case is now a modal view controller ontop of View Controller A so you can't use

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController];
```

Comment: this takes me to view B becuase B is root view controller of navigation object. I come to viewcontroller B from A by using [self presentViewController:VCB animated:YES]; in A class.

Comment: Yes, so in View Controller B, you call [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; or am I misunderstanidng something? Are you saying calling dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: in viewControllerC brings you to ViewControllerB instead of viewControllerA?

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; works and takes me back to A. Thanks for help. I am accepting it.

Comment: It should work if you call [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] in ViewControllerC!

Answer (score 1):

comment under your post will retur you to the B controller. Use `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: this takes me to view B becuase B is root view controller of navigation object. I come to viewcontroller B from A by using [self presentViewController:VCB animated:YES]; in A class.

Comment: this is extremly bad practice. You should init your navigation controller with A as a root, and then pushNavigationController to B,C,D to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Call `-popViewControllerAnimated:` of the `navigationViewController`

```
[viewcontrollerC.navigationViewController popViewcontrollerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: this takes me to view B. Becuase B is root view controller of navigation object. I come to viewcontroller B from A by using [self presentViewController:VCB animated:YES]; in A class.

Comment: You're presenting VCB modally, try `-dismissViewController` in VCB.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (AViewController *vc in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass: [AViewController class]]) { 
      [[self navigationController] popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Using this code, you can go to the `AViewController`. :)

Comment: this takes me to view B. Becuase B is root view controller of navigation object. I come to viewcontroller B from A by using  [self presentViewController:VCB animated:YES]; in A class.

Comment: If you are using UINavigationController, why aren't you pushing into it?

Comment: Uiviewcontroller B is root View controller of UINavigation controller. So, I push and reach to C from B. BUt, from B i want to go directly to uiviewcontorller A. A is simple uiviewcontorller without Uinavigation contorller. TO make crear A ->prsenetviewcontoroller -> Uinavigitoncotontroller with B as root view controller -> push to C . Now, with some action in B, i want to go back to A.

Answer (score 0):

By Writing the First Line you get the Indexes of all View Controllers and from second Line You will reach up to your Destination.

NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];